# ¿Cómo saber si una variable fue declarada en Java?

Tags: java, condiciones

Tengo una variable "x"

que a veces me llega declarada y a veces no.

quiero un if para hacer esto:

```
if (esta definida) {
  //si no esta definida:
  x = "blablabla";
} else {
  //si esta definida:
  String x = "blablabla";
}
```

Comment: Hola, primero debes escribir en formato de código, después que es imposible que no esté declarada una variable ya que el ide (NetBeans, Eclipse, etc.) no te lo permite

Comment: Lo más parecido a lo que propones es tener un parámetro que pueda ser `null`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cuando decis declarada, querras decir si tiene un valor o no??? todas las variables en Java estan declaradas, siempre....

Comment: Para el `if` no hace ninguna diferencia que la variable esté definida o no.

Answer (score 1):

Una variable en java siempre debe estar declarada. Pero puede o no contener un valor.

La forma de representar que un valor no ha sido declarado a una variable es lo que llamamos `null` y es una palabra especial en casi todos los lenguajes.

Así que para tu caso

```
String x = null

if(x == null) {
    System.out.println("La variable no tiene valor asignado le ponemos algo");
    x = "valor impuesto"
}
```

Es especialmente importante recalcar que existe otro concepto llamado el "zero value" que no es mas que el valor cero para un tipo dado y es importante tener en cuenta que esto, por algún motivo, no es estándard para todos los lenguajes

Por ejemplo, para un entero el valor cero es... sí, el 0.

Para un real es 0.0

Para una cadena de texto el valor cero es una cadena vacía ""

Para una lista una lista vacía

Para un mapa un mapa vacío

Y un bonus que siempre me ha gustado, para un objeto de cooredenadas x,y es.. [null island!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island) (este en concreto no es estándard pero siempre me ha hecho gracia)

Comment: En Java no existe *zero value* como concepto, sino ***default value***. El *default value* para tipos numéricos primitivos es, como bien dices, 0, para `boolean` es `false` y para objetos (`String`s, listas, mapas, etc.) es `null`.

Comment: Siento discrepar pero el "default value" es algo totalmente distinto. El zero value es un concepto en cuanto a cual es el valor usado para indicar un valor neutro (cero). Mientras que el default value es que valor se asignará a un objeto si se le instancia sin valor. Uno es un concepto mas matemático mientras que el otro es un concepto de programación

Comment: El *zero value* es un concepto que solamente a visto en la documentación de Go y está relacionado a la inicialización por defecto de las variables. En el lenguaje de programación Java este concepto de *zero value* no se maneja sino solamente el de *default value*. No obstante, si extrapolamos dicho concepto a Java, el "zero value" para `String`s no es `""` sino `null`. Lo mismo para listas, mapas, o cualquier *reference type*.

Answer (score 1):

Desde Java 8 existe la clase `Optional` que sirve para declarar un contenedor que puede tener un objeto o no.

Por ejemplo el segundo apellido de una persona podría considerarse opcional en el caso de que esa persona fuese estadounidense.

Si definisemos el getter de una clase persona, donde el apellido fuese opcional lo podríamos hacer así:

```
public Optional<String> getSegundoApellido() {
  if (soyEstadounidense()) {
     return Optional.empty();
  } else {
     return Optional.of(segundoApellido);
  }
}
```

En el caso de ser estadounidense se devuelve `Optional.empty()`, es decir un contenedor vacío y en el caso de que no sea estadounidense se devuelve un contenedor `Optional` que contiene el segundo apellido. Eso lo hacemos con `Optional.of()`

Cuando queramos trabajar con este valor opcional haremos algo así:

```
String nombre = persona.getNombre();
String apellido1 = persona.getPrimerApellido();
Optional<String> apellido2 = persona.getSegundoApellido();

if (apellido2.isPresent()) {
  System.out.println(nombre + " " + apellido1 + " " + apellido2.get());
} else {
  System.out.println(nombre + " " + apellido1);
}
```

Aquí se puede apreciar que para ver si el contenedor tiene algo dentro se utiliza `isPresent()`  y para obtener el valor del contenedor se utiliza `get()`.

Más información:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html
- https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        //usando null
        String x =null;//inicializamos con valor null obligatoriamente
        
        //si variable x es distinto de null
        if(x !=null)
        {
            System.out.println("La variable x No es nula");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("La variable x es nula");
        }
        
        
        //usando cadena vacía
        String x2 ="";//inicializamos cadena vacía obligatoriamente
        
        //si la cadena de texto x2 no está vacía
        if(!x2.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("La variable x2 No está vacía");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("La variable x2 está vacía");
        }
```

Comment: Por favor mira [answer]... esta respuesta es solo codigo...

Comment: Perdón, creía que los comentarios en el código contaban